# How to correctly install Braintree using cocoa pod?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, braintree

I am trying to install Braintree SDK using cocoapods.
This is what I used to install - `pod 'Braintree'`

When installing the terminal shows content as below -

```
Installing Braintree (3.1.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `NewTest.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total
pod installed.

[!] Can't merge user_target_xcconfig for pod targets: ["Braintree", "Drop-In", "PayPal", "UI", "api"]. Boolean build setting GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS has different values.

[!] Can't merge user_target_xcconfig for pod targets: ["Braintree", "Drop-In", "PayPal", "UI", "api"]. Boolean build setting GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS has different values.
```

After installation if I do `#import <BraintreeCore/BraintreeCore.h>` I get a file not found error for the same statement.

Here is my Podfile-

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'NewTest' do
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
# use_frameworks!

pod 'Braintree'
# Pods for NewTest

end
```

I also checked `pod --version` which is showing  -

```
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@global/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:140: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
1.0.1
```

Comment: Just wondering, are you sure you opened your project through your workspace?

Comment: Also, in these circumstances it helps noting which cocoapods version you are using

Comment: Yes I opened the project through workspace.

Answer (score 0):

It seems my cocoapods is not downloading the correct version.Rest of the configuraton is correct.